# Identifying a series of numbers $\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{192},\frac{1}{9216},... $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series of numbers (starting from index n=1):
$$\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{192},\frac{1}{9216},... $$

I notice that all of the denominators are divisible by 8, but I can't seem to find a general rule for this series. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: After dividing by $8$, you have $\frac 11,\frac 1{24},\frac 1{1048},\dots$.  Do you have more terms?

Comment: @abiessu, check your arithmetic.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : It is not showing anything for $8,192,9216$.. It is showing some results for $8,192$ but the next term is $92160$.. I am afraid there is a typo in the question... not very sure though..

Comment: Try writing each denominator in the form $2^r3^s$.

Comment: The third term should be indeed $\frac{1}{9216}$. There is no typo (unfortunately).

Comment: @Bob : Ok.. as you have confirmed now i can proceed with my own brains instead of believing that encyclopedia :D

Comment: Rule of thumb: if the sequence is in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, then you can find it there yourself. If it's not in the OEIS, and we are asked, without any context, how it was constructed, then most of us will be hard-pressed to care. It's nothing personal; it's just that this sort of question tends to be for IQ tests and other such instruments, not the actual practice of mathematics.

Comment: @gerrymyerson: the faulty arithmetic of mine strikes again... I should have looked for a multiple of $1024$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$8=2^3,192=2^6\cdot3,9216=2^{10}\cdot3^2$

Now the $n$ th term of the powers of $3$ will be the $n$th term of  $0,1,2$ which is $n-1$

the $n$ th term of the powers of $2$ will be the $n$th term of $\displaystyle3=1+2,6=1+2+3,10=1+2+3+4$ which is $\displaystyle1+2+\cdots+n+n+1=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}2$

Comment: "will be" should be "might be". Frankly there is nothing you can say for certain with so little data.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, when (with how much data) can we really say for certain?

Comment: Never, of course. This kind of question is just not suitable for this site (but it's fine for OEIS).

Comment: That is why I voted to close as "primarily opinion-based". In my opinion, these are the values at $1$, $2$, and $3$ of a certain quadratic equation.

Comment: Well, also $$8\;,\;192=8\cdot 24\;,\;9216=192\cdot 48\;,\;\;...9216\cdot 72??$$

Answer (score 4):

Start by factoring the denominators completely: $8=2^3$, $192=2^6\cdot3$, and $9216=2^{10}\cdot3^2$. The powers of $3$ seem to be increasing in a very simple way. Do you recognize $3,6,10$ as part of a familiar sequence of numbers? HINT: Imagine it with a first term of $1$, so that it’s $1,3,6,10$.

Comment: Well, the three is being raised to a power of $n-1$. I'm not sure what to do with the power of 2 though?

Comment: @Bob: $1=1$, $1+2=3$, $1+2+3=6$, $1+2+3+4=10$, ...

Comment: I see. How do you take that in to a recurrence formula? It looks like a a factorial except with addition instead of multiplication.

Comment: @Bob: If your terms are numbered starting with $0$, and $a_k$ is the exponent on $2$ in term $k$, then $a_0=3$, and $a_{k+1}=a_k+k+3$; try it and see.